# set image at center of background with inner space arround a button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I have set a background image to a button and have applied `layer.cornerRadius` to that button so that a button is just like a circle, but the image is being cut from corners so how can I place image at the center of a button so that when I apply the `layer.cornerRadius` should not cut the image from corners, is there a way so that I can make an space from inner side to a buttons frame.

Here is what I have tried yet:

```
myCheckBoxButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "check-square"), for: .normal)
myCheckBoxButton.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 10, width: 40, height: 40)
myCheckBoxButton.backgroundColor = .blue
myCheckBoxButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
myCheckBoxButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
myCheckName.text = "Checkbox"
myCheckName.textColor = .gray
myCheckName.frame = CGRect(x: 100 , y: 60, width: 80, height: 15)
```

[image]

**Update after aleksmutlu's answer**

everything is right but the image is not white transparent it seems blue

[image]

**Update Done**

added button type as custom

```
let myCheckBoxButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

Comment: How about a uiimage under a button? You'll have more options for sizing the image that way.

Comment: It seems that the button will not scale the background image to the button size. You should try to use a scaled image which has the desired size of 40x40 pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting a background image, you can set the image as the content of the button and give it some insets.

```
myCheckBoxButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "check-square"), for: .normal)
myCheckBoxButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Comment: updated question its correct but image is not white it seems blue? any idea

Comment: You should set the button type to "Custom"

Comment: would you write in answer please

Comment: I am creating buttons programmatically!! how can I assign??

Comment: thanx done   `let myCheckBoxButton = UIButton(type: .custom)`